# I want to code a claim function in my ERC20 smart contract and want to limit the claimants to only those who hold an NFT from a particular collection

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, erc-721, mint

I'm writing a smart contract for an ERC 20 token that is pausable and mintable in the sense that more tokens can be created by the contract owner.

I want to add a claim functionality for the holders of a particular NFT collection - each NFT owner can claim 100 tokens per NFT. If they sell the NFT on, the new owner of the NFT can also claim a 100 tokens max.

I'm new to coding and i would appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: Hi, this is doable but not achievable without breaking a protocol if you plan on having this as a live, working product. You said that if they sell the NFT, the new owner can also claim 100 tokens max. But this does not stop the user from creating 1000 accounts and simply send their NFT to claim more tokens.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. The token is designed to be used for a free game and everybody enters into the game by purchasing an NFT. All new token holders wait for a set date when the contract is unpaused and they can mint the token. They may try and game the system by transferring the nft and buying from different wallets. Once the designated 3-5 min expires the admin of the contract pauses the contract again and no more ERC20 tokens can be minted. I need help with coding this claim function for the holders of the NFT. I don't know what the syntax is.

Comment: if it's a mintable token, then this smart contract will call the mint function for 100 tokens every time your user calls it. Just verify if the NFT is within the user's wallet.

Comment: I need help coding that verify function. how does the smart contract check if token from another wallet is present?